# GET request with PYTHON script

Tags: python, http, tomcat, get

I have the following issue.

I deployed a REST service on Tomcat 9 and I'm able to send a request by browser.
For example,

```
http://localhost:8080/my_app/ping
```

gives me the expected "Hello world" string.

Now, I'm trying to send the same GET request by Python script:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/my_app/ping')
print(r.content)
```

receiving

```
"HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" ... "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".
```

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks

ADD: Same behaviour using curl

Comment: Wild guess : there might be some authentication/authorization stuff on your tomcat server, for which you already have a valid auth cookie in your browser.

Comment: I see nothing that could explain this behavior from what you have post. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers How could I solve for Python?

Comment: Try another request pathway other than your browser, like a `curl` command line. You don't know yet if the issue is a problem in your Python solution, or a special behavior of your browser as Bruno suggested.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I've just updated my question. I have the same problem with `curl`

Comment: Now you know the problem isn't unique to your Python solution. Follow up on Bruno's suggestion and figure out why the browser approach does work. Some guesses: authentication, user agent filtering, cookies, ??

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Using the Firefox tools, I got the cURL string: `curl 'http://localhost:8080/my_app/ping' -H 'Host: localhost:8080' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en; q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'   ` Now `curl` works. What should I add to the Python request?

Comment: @Fab requests has a very decent doc : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Try adding the headers you see from the curl request (the `-H` items) one by one and see which are required. The `requests` doco shows how to provide headers.

Comment: I noted a strange behavior. After performing the curl call extracted from the browser, both curl and python get requests work.